# C# Access Denied when trying to Copy and XML file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mobile

c# question  here. I keep getting access is denied when trying to move an xml file. I know the problem is that it is creating a temporary XML file with no admin privileges which its needs, and I have tried editing the appmanifest with the require admin = true line to no avail.  I have also tried setting the permissions outside the program and running visual studio as an admin.

```
Link to the pastebin code.
https://pastebin.com/M7dRTXHY
```

[image]

I actually got an answer for this using completely different code yesterday but my teacher said I must do it this way. I have spent hours trying to debug this and am losing my mind.

It is a windows 10 phone application as well, not sure if that changes anything.

I realise there is a million and one other questions similar to this but I cannot get anything to work.

This is the exact tutorial I was following taken straight from my course. [image]

Comment: Isn't `InstalledLocation` is a read-only folder? You are trying to do a Move on a file from it, which would try delete the source file, but there's no permission to do that. See if Copy works, as that will eliminate permission issue on the destination.

Comment: Hey james thanks for the reply. I am leaning towards I was taught incorrectly but I uploaded a picture of the tutorial, would you be able to take a look and see if I made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the StorageFile for the move/copy/delete etc operations:

```
private async void Grid_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
{
   Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
   StorageFolder installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
   StorageFolder targetLocation = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

   var targetFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("Contacts.xml");
   await targetFile.MoveAsync(targetLocation);
   TARGETFILEPATH = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path.ToString() + "\\Contacts.xml";
   loadContacts();
}
```

more on StorageFiles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile).

Comment: Hey mate thanks fort he reply. This is how I was shown how to do it by my course. Are you saying this is wrong. http://imgur.com/a/5BFzB
I wouldnt not surprise me if the course was wrong. I just want to make sure it was not my error.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comment. Does that also mean that the loadContacts() here https://pastebin.com/YUigWa46 is also wrong. Obvisouly I need to figure out what to change the TARGETFILEPATH too since it no longer exists, but is this way off?

Comment: @Rick1990, i modified my answer and added the TARGETFILEPATH initialization. now the loadContacts() should work as expected.

Comment: I have tried the solution and I get an error stating that http://imgur.com/a/koPhh

If I dont get that error I get the error stating that file is not found. I tried googling this error but all it said was the change the contacts.xml file to content and copy always which it was already set at.

Comment: @Rick1990, when you move the file it will be moved, so next time you will get  "FileNotFoundException" because it was moved to the target directory, if you will recompile  the file will be copied again to the project folder but when you will try to move it you will get "FileAlreadyExists" , so to summarize you will have to delete the file if it already exists in the TargetPath, and recompile your project after each successful move to put it back in your appx folder.